# Serve logs through web interface rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, logging, nginx, unicorn

I have a web application built with ruby on rails. It is served by Nginx through unicorn, the application is running on a Ubuntu server VPS.
I have 4 log files:

- nginx's access log
- nginx's error log
- rails' production log
- unicorn's log

I have implemented a user login system and I want to be able to serve this log files to some user profiles.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try [GrayLog](https://www.graylog.org/overview/). It's an open-source tool, collecting your system logs and building graphs on them, providing some filtration opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple web log reading i would recommend [Browserlog](https://github.com/dieb/browserlog), very simple.
However, currently it can read only rails log (according to environment)

Graylog is awesome tool but it require time to setup.